# Use top-level makefile in subdirectories

Tags: makefile, subdirectory

I have a project with a directory structure like this:

```
╷ /
├ Makefile
├┐ dir1/
│├ foo.in
│└ foo.out
├┐ dir2/
┊┊
```

and the Makefile contains rules for all file in the project, e.g.

```
dir1/%.out: dir1/%.in
    gen_out $< $@
```

If I am in the top level directory, I can run `make dir1/foo.out` just fine.

The question is: What is the most elegant way that calling `make foo.out` inside `dir1` has the same effect?

Answer (score 1):

Your choices are limited.  You can use the `-f ../Makefile` flag on the `make` command line, maybe by writing a wrapper script around `make` that will determine the current location and invoke it with the proper flags depending on where you are.

You can set the `MAKEFILES` environment variable to contain the fully-qualified pathname of the makefile.

You can create a little mini-makefile in each directory which does nothing except re-invoke `$(MAKE)` with the proper top-level makefile.

Comment: These do not work as expected, probably because make does not take the current working directory into account when interpreting the target: `make -f ../Makefile foo.out` in `dir1` will *not* rebuild `foo.out`. What works is `make -C .. dir1/foo.out`, but then I’m not passing the files real name, relative to the current location, to make.

Comment: Well, you didn't say that your working directory had to be the root when you asked your question.  In that case you cannot use `MAKEFILES` so you'll have to either write a script that can invoke make, or else create mini-makefiles.  You can do this so that it will invoke make correctly: e.g., convert the target "foo.out" to "dir1/foo.out" before running make in the parent directory.  It will be somewhat complex since presumably you don't want to translate generic targets like `all`, `clean`, etc. into `dir1/all`, `dir1/clean`, etc.  But do-able.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same, but hoping for something more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that easily with [makepp](http://makepp.sourceforge.net/).  Just rename your Makefile to RootMakeppfile.  This will be loaded first where ever you are in your tree.

Unlike traditional makes, makepp does not need to do recursive builds.  So you can also put a Makefile into each directory, and makepp will load all the ones you need into one process.  That way it has a consistent view of your whole project, and can detect and keep track of all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I need a solution that works on other team member’s systems without extra tool installations.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd dir1 && make -f ../Makefile foo.out
```